# Is it possible to write

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, continuous-aspect

Is it possible to write: they were driving for an hour, then they stopped near the cafe. ? I mean, are the tenses I've used correct?

Comment: It might be correct in a narrative written in a certain voice, but is not proper use of tenses in a stand-alone sentence.

Comment: *Things became difficult and they left the house quickly.  They were driving for an hour, then they stopped near the cafe.  Would it be open? The events of the past twenty-four hours seemed unreal.  How could they possibly make things better ?...*  Yup, it's a curious narrative voice - and hard to sustain.  Familiar but definitely 'genre'.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't awful, but it isn't quite right.  Instead of

> They were driving for an hour, then they stopped near the cafe.

better is

> They drove for an hour, then they stopped near the cafe.

or

> They had been driving for an hour, when they stopped near the cafe.